# Build a JSON with an Array of objects

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to build an array of objects,
something like this

```
     [
      { name: "joe", id: "123"},
      { name: "ken", id: "234"},
      { name: "dave", id: "987"}
    ]
```

End goal is to return this as a JSON object in API response. I'd like to use JSON.simple, Greatly appreciate any suggestions,

I am sure there is better way to code, below is what I have currently,

```
am sure there is better way to code, below is what I have currently,
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        obj1.put("id", "123");
        obj1.put("name", "joe");
    JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("id", "234");
        obj2.put("name", "ken");
    JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject();
        obj3.put("id", "987");
        obj3.put("name", "dave");
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    list.add(obj1);
    list.add(obj2);
    list.add(obj3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a Class representing the data you want to transform into JSon

```
class Person {
   private String name;
   private String id;
}
```

Then use a Serialization library to transform the object list to JSon.

For example : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson